# Source that Adam and Eve ate from the Tree of Knowledge because they desired autonomy

Tags: sources-mekorot, parashat-bereishit, adam, eve-chava

I remember hearing once that Adam and Eve ate from the Tree of Knowledge because they found G-d's presence in the Garden of Eden to be overbearing and they desired autonomy, so they rejected his sole commandment, that they are not to eat from the Eitz Hadas. This would fit with their punishment, which, while obviously a punishment, grants them a much greater sense of control over their life.

Does anyone know where it says that they ate for that reason? Thanks.

Comment: Sort of see Michtav Me'Eliyahu - *Adam ha'Rishon chatah lishmah biheyoso rotzeh le'harchiv shetach bechiraso*.

Comment: @Eliyahu They wanted autonomy seems to connect with Genesis 3:5 and 3:14 with Rashi. See there. They were being offered by the snake to become like G-d to be able to create their own world. The offer was considered temptation to idolatry.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Yeah, the Michtav Mei'eliyahu is sort of similar, but is really saying a Vort that is too dissimilar to what I am saying for my purposes.

Comment: @DavidKenner Genesis 3:5 is a great proof. Not sure what you see from 3:14. Can you explain? Thanks

Comment: I think Ramban says this, but I'm not certian.